# Javascript regex match coming up null

Tags: javascript, html, regex, null, match

I'm trying to write a javascript function that receives a string, and counts the amount of vowels. Displaying the count of each vowel, as well as a grand total. It works fine if every vowel is in the string, but if for example there aren't an A's or E's, it will return null.

Is there a way I can intercept this and replace null's with 0? Or is there a more efficient way to achieve this? Thank you to anyone who can help!

```js
function countVowels(inString) {
  return outString = (
    "Total vowels: " + inString.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length +
    "\nTotal A's: " + inString.match(/[a]/gi).length +
    "\nTotal E's: " + inString.match(/[e]/gi).length +
    "\nTotal I's: " + inString.match(/[i]/gi).length +
    "\nTotal O's: " + inString.match(/[o]/gi).length +
    "\nTotal U's: " + inString.match(/[u]/gi).length
  );
}
```

```html
<form>
  Enter a string to count its vowels. <br>
  <input type="text" id="inString"><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="console.log(countVowels(inString.value))">Count vowels</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah, `match` is kind of annoying that way. I’d try a different approach: writing a `function count(string, letter)` that counts the number of instances of `letter` in `string`, and calling it with `count(inString, 'a')`, `count(inString, 'e')`, etc.. You can save each of those and add them together to get the total number of vowels.

Comment: Instead of `/[a]/gi`, you can use `/a/gi`. This won't solve your issue, but it's a little cleaner...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `|| []` as a default "return value" in case `.match` returns `null`:

```js
function countVowels(inString) {
  return outString = (
    "Total vowels: " + (inString.match(/[aeiou]/gi) || []).length +
    "\nTotal A's: " + (inString.match(/a/gi) || []).length +
    "\nTotal E's: " + (inString.match(/e/gi) || []).length +
    "\nTotal I's: " + (inString.match(/i/gi) || []).length +
    "\nTotal O's: " + (inString.match(/o/gi) || []).length +
    "\nTotal U's: " + (inString.match(/u/gi) || []).length
  );
}
```

```html
<form>
  Enter a string to count its vowels. <br>
  <input type="text" id="inString"><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="console.log(countVowels(inString.value))">Count vowels</button>
</form>
```

Also, notice I removed the `[]` from all single-character matches. In regexes, `[a]` and `a` are equivalent.

The `||` will return the left side of the operator if that side is ["truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).
If the left side is ["falsy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), the `||` will always return the right side of the statement, which is our default value.

If the `.match` finds any results, it returns an array, which is "truthy".
If the `.match` does not find any results, it returns `null`, which is "falsy".

Comment: In case someone comes across this answer while searching for a way to _return the match or a default value_, this is the way to do it in a one-liner: `(myString.match(<the matching pattern>) || ['', 'the default value'])[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is not in regex but in logic.

For a given `inString` say *test*, it does not have vowel `a` or `o`. So the regex will not find any match and this will fail.

You can try something like this:

**Original Code:**

```js
function countVowels(inString) {
  return outString = (
    "Total vowels: " + (inString.match(/[aeiou]/gi) || []).length +
    "\nTotal A's: " + (inString.match(/[a]/gi) || []).length +
    "\nTotal E's: " + (inString.match(/[e]/gi) || []).length +
    "\nTotal I's: " + (inString.match(/[i]/gi) || []).length +
    "\nTotal O's: " + (inString.match(/[o]/gi) || []).length +
    "\nTotal U's: " + (inString.match(/[u]/gi) || []).length
  );
}
```

```html
<form>
  Enter a string to count its vowels. <br>
  <input type="text" id="inString"><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="console.log(countVowels(inString.value))">Count vowels</button>
</form>
```

**Updated Code**

```js
function countVowels(inString) {
  var vowels = "aeiou";
  var ret = "Total vowels: " + getMatchLength(inString, vowels);
  for(var i = 0; i< vowels.length; i++)
    ret += "\nTotal " + vowels[i].toUpperCase() + "'s: " + getMatchLength(inString, vowels[i])
  return ret;
}

function getMatchLength(str, chars) {
  return (str.match(new RegExp("["+ chars + "]")) || []).length;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Enter a string to count its vowels. <br>
  <input type="text" id="inString"><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="console.log(countVowels(inString.value))">Count vowels</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add use conditional operator to output 0 instead of `length` when the result of `match` is `null`.

To make it more readable, you can get the lengths beforehand and then use it in your final string.

```js
function countVowels(inString) {
  var aCount = inString.match(/[a]/gi) !== null ? inString.match(/[a]/gi).length : 0;
  
  var eCount = inString.match(/[e]/gi) !== null ? inString.match(/[a]/gi).length : 0;
  
  var iCount = inString.match(/[i]/gi) !== null ? inString.match(/[a]/gi).length : 0;
  
  var oCount = inString.match(/[o]/gi) !== null ? inString.match(/[a]/gi).length : 0;
  
  var uCount = inString.match(/[u]/gi) !== null ? inString.match(/[a]/gi).length : 0;
  
  var vowelsCount = aCount + eCount + iCount + oCount + uCount;
  
  var outString = "Total vowels: " + vowelsCount + 
  "\nTotal A's: " + aCount + 
  "\nTotal E's: " + eCount + 
  "\nTotal I's: " + iCount + 
  "\nTotal O's: " + oCount + 
  "\nTotal U's: " + uCount;
  
  return outString;
}
```

```html
<form>
 Enter a string to count its vowels. <br>
 <input type="text" id="inString"><br>
 <button type="button" onclick="console.log(countVowels(inString.value))">Count vowels</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: this is kind of wasteful, since you're executing every regex match twice.

Comment: @TimothyGroote yes, you're right. Just checked Cerbrus's answer below. Thanks for pointing out.